# webpack-dev-server open and host opens wrong URL

Tags: webpack-dev-server

Per the docs [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-open) and [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-host), I have the following in my package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "webpack-dev-server --host 0.0.0.0 --open",
  ...
```

With just `--open` it opens `localhost:8080` when I run `npm start`. When I add in `--host 0.0.0.0` it still opens, but opens `0.0.0.0:8080` and gives me `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` in the browser.  I can manually change it to `localhost:8080` and it loads the page just fine.

I tried `--host 0.0.0.0 --open --open-page localhost:8080` and it dutifully opens `http://0.0.0.0:8080/localhost:8080` for me in the browser.

Has anyone gotten these two options to play nicely together?

Comment: Not sure if something like `<my machine IP>:8080` would work, but I'm not much inclined to try, since its.. y'know.. in git. I assumed the `0.0.0.0` is a hint to listen for traffic on whatever machine it's run on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below works fine for me

```
webpack-dev-server -p --public 127.0.0.1:9000 --host 0.0.0.0 --port 9000
```

`--host` is the listening interface. `--public` is for what would be opened in the browser. And `--open-page` is for appending the page url after the main domain

Comment: awesome - thanks.  I'm now using `webpack-dev-server -p --public localhost:8080 --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8080 --open` and it's working great. The `--public` option was what I was missing.